# Modify access time of Windows read only file through WSL

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a read-only file, say samp.txt and I run the following on PowerShell:

```
> $file = Get-Item .\samp.txt
> $file.LastAccessTime = (get-date)
```

we get: `"Access to the path 'G:\Study_Material\Coding\samp.txt' is denied."`

Now before we proceed, look at the access time:
`> $file.LastAccessTime` will be

```
Sunday, December 30, 2018 11:02:49 PM
```

Now we open WSL and do: `$ touch samp.txt`

Back to PowerShell we do:

```
> $file = Get-Item .\samp.txt
> $file.LastAccessTime
```

we get:

```
Sunday, December 30, 2018 11:19:16 PM
```

Thus it has been modified with no elevated privileges.

Now my question: How is it possible to mimic this action in PowerShell alone without removing the `ReadOnly` tag by modifying the `$file.Attributes`.

Comment: The readonly attribute protects file data, not metadata. It shouldn't prevent opening the file with `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` access or cause [`SetFileTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime) to fail. Python's `os.utime` calls the latter function on Windows, and it works fine for a readonly file. I'll look into why PowerShell fails here.

Comment: It's a .NET bug. The implementation of [`System.IO.File.SetLastAccessTimeUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setlastaccesstimeutc?view=netframework-4.7.2) tries to open the file with `GENERIC_WRITE` access, which is more than is required and fails for a readonly file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So does the touch command or os.utime open the file in a different mode?

Comment: Python's `os.utime` requests write-attributes access. This is in addition to the minimum  that `CreateFile` always requests: read-attributes and synchronize access. In contrast, generic-write access includes write-data and append-data access, which isn't allowed for a readonly file.

Comment: Linux `touch` is based on `utimensat`. At first `touch` tries to get write access, but it can't because of the readonly attribute (mapped in WSL as no write permission, but it should map to the "immutable" attribute, with NTFS semantics). It can still succeed without a write-enabled fd since the times are just to be made current and the caller is the owner. WSL uses the Windows session user as the owner of all files when it mounts volumes under "/mnt", so that's not enough by itself. It has to do another NT access check to determine if the user has the required write-attributes access.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with ReadOnly files, you cannot simply change the LastAccessTime.
(see the comments by [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) ).

In order to have it work in PowerShell, you need to first remove the ReadOnly flag from the file's attributes, do the change and reset the ReadOnly flag like so:

```
$file = Get-Item .\samp.txt -Force

# test if the ReadOnly flag on the file is set
if ($file.Attributes -band 1) {
    # remove the ReadOnly flag from the file. (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 1)
    $file.Attributes = $file.Attributes -bxor 1
    # or use: $file | Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false

    $file.LastAccessTime = (Get-Date)

    # reset the ReadOnly flag
    $file.Attributes = $file.Attributes -bxor 1
    # or use: $file | Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
}
else {
    # the file is not ReadOnly, so just do the 'touch' on the LastAccessTime
    $file.LastAccessTime = (Get-Date)
}
```

You can read all about file attributes and their numeric values [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-attribute-constants)

Comment: It would be cleaner and self-documenting to use `[System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly` instead of the magic number "1".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as eryksun mentioned in his first comment, shouldn't the file meta data not be affected by the read only tag as in case of how Linux handles it?

Comment: @GaneshK, PowerShell is a .NET program, and this is working around the bug (or at least design flaw) in its `SetLastAccessTimeUtc` method, which requests more access than the operation requires.